# Markdown for Reproducible Research in Python

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reproducible-research

I would like to know whether there is something equivalent to R-markdown in Python which can help me do reproducible research.

**Please note: I'm not interested in IPython Notebooks as an answer**.

I want to have the syntactic joy of r-markdown with code in python. I know that one can supply `engine="python"` in r-markdown and get going but the problem comes when you want to include plots produced using matplotlib in the reproducible doc by simply writing `plt.show()` where `plt` is alias to `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Do you know about any such modules / tools in python which can help me achieve this? I want to use such tools with Spyder / IntelliJ.

I would also like the option similar to `echo=FALSE` to be present in such a tool.

If no such project exists, then do you guys know about someone / some organization who are working on such a thing.

Comment: Sir, if in any case you want to put this question on hold, then please suggest a site where I can ask this question and expect a reply.

Comment: Pity that this question does not fit the stack overflow. Here is candidate for what OP (and me) was looking for: http://mpastell.com/pweave/

Comment: @NaimishAgarwal look for python package Pweave (0.25)                                             - Scientific reports with embedded python computations with reST, LaTeX or markdown (it is shame it was closed).

Comment: @psarka I share your view on the off-topic point and very good answer !